# How do I give a custom button the functionality to Create a New Record (on a related list)

Tags: custom-button, custom, create-records, new

I created a custom button "Add" and put in on the related list. But I need some help figuring out how to give it the same functionality of "New" when clicked

[image]

Comment: What does it do now?

Comment: "Add" has no functionality now, I hoping to have it open up a New Record modal

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a quick action for this. [Here is the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_object_specific_actions.htm&type=5). If you want you can even go so far as to add some level of automation to your quick action [using a macro.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/service_macros/units/service_macros_setup)

Normally I would copy the text from the page over but it's a length page.

If you can't accomplish what you need with the quick action you'll need a lightning component which is much more complicated. You can use [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules) to learn more about quick actions and lightning components as well.

- [Lightning Component basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics)
- [Create Object Specific Quick Actions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/units/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_objectspecific)

Comment: I looked into Quick Actions, though it looks like it needs to be in the form of a button so that it can be displayed on a related list

Comment: I posted another answer that you can use for those types of buttons. I'm not removing this one as it's still useful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer, while useful, was base don misunderstanding of the question so I'm posting another answer.

To accomplish what you want you can use a URL hack. Go to the new page for the object you're trying to create and copy the URL, then use that URL as the location for your button.

[This is a great article for URL hacks](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/).

Comment: URL hacks are, well, hacks, and they have a tendency to break when Salesforce makes significant changes to its URL structure. Example: Lightning Experience. The question asked here involves LEX, so I don't think that the cited URL hacks will work here.

Comment: I completely agree on hacks, only posted cause I was thinking in classic. You're probably right that URL hacks likely don't work in LEX but this answer could still help a user who stumbles onto the question that doesn't use LEX so I'll leave it up.